# elasticsearch installation failure - cannot generate (1) password and (2) enrollment token for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to start using elasticsearch (with Mac x64-based) for incorporating a full-text search into a Flask web application, but have been stuck with its installation ever since the very beginning despite numerous attempts. Basically, the two errors listed below are hindering me from moving forward.

```
❌ Unable to auto-generate the password for the elastic built-in superuser. 
❌ Unable to generate an enrollment token for Kibana instances, try invoking `bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana`.
```

The `elastic_server.log` gave the following "WARN" and "ERROR" messages:

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-09T08:13:03.916Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw][IPaddress][/Users/Desktop/elasticsearch-8.9.2/data] free: 38.4gb[4.1%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[IPaddress][management][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.DiskThresholdMonitor","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"NZqmDBtIT26z1AUWAWIQLQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw","elasticsearch.node.name":"IPaddress","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
```

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-09T08:13:33.919Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw][IPaddress][/Users/Desktop/elasticsearch-8.9.2/data] free: 38.4gb[4.1%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[IPaddress][generic][T#11]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.DiskThresholdMonitor","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"NZqmDBtIT26z1AUWAWIQLQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw","elasticsearch.node.name":"IPaddress","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
```

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-09T08:13:43.269Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"Failed to create enrollment token when generating API key", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[IPaddress][generic][T#16]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.enrollment.InternalEnrollmentTokenGenerator","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"NZqmDBtIT26z1AUWAWIQLQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw","elasticsearch.node.name":"IPaddress","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException","error.message":"[.security-7][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.security-7][0]] containing [index {[.security][Ov8AeYoBoJSypFN9FBDe], source[{\"doc_type\":\"api_key\",\"type\":\"rest\",\"creation_time\":1694247163107,\"expiration_time\":1694248963107,\"api_key_invalidated\":false,\"api_key_hash\":\"{PBKDF2}10000$Q3db6H1PJGk2NJegKLvzTGAGqZn8/TjhSb10FO8PPkY=$9OGowE27XGElimoA8Nu2x6ah66Joz0Tj8cw4hW66F1s=\",\"role_descriptors\":{\"create_enrollment_token\":{\"cluster\":[\"cluster:admin/xpack/security/enroll/kibana\"],\"indices\":[],\"applications\":[],\"run_as\":[],\"metadata\":{},\"type\":\"role\"}},\"limited_by_role_descriptors\":{\"_xpack_security\":{\"cluster\":[\"all\"],\"indices\":[{\"names\":[\"*\"],\"privileges\":[\"all\"],\"allow_restricted_indices\":true}],\"applications\":[],\"run_as\":[\"*\"],\"metadata\":{\"_reserved\":true},\"type\":\"role\"}},\"name\":\"enrollment_token_API_key_Of8AeYoBoJSypFN9FBDd\",\"version\":8090299,\"metadata_flattened\":null,\"creator\":{\"principal\":\"_xpack_security\",\"full_name\":null,\"email\":null,\"metadata\":{},\"realm\":\"__attach\",\"realm_type\":\"__attach\"}}]}] blocking until refresh]","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [.security-7][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.security-7][0]] containing [index {[.security][Ov8AeYoBoJSypFN9FBDe], source[{\"doc_type\":\"api_key\",\"type\":\"rest\",\"creation_time\":1694247163107,\"expiration_time\":1694248963107,\"api_key_invalidated\":false,\"api_key_hash\":\"{PBKDF2}10000$Q3db6H1PJGk2NJegKLvzTGAGqZn8/TjhSb10FO8PPkY=$9OGowE27XGElimoA8Nu2x6ah66Joz0Tj8cw4hW66F1s=\",\"role_descriptors\":{\"create_enrollment_token\":{\"cluster\":[\"cluster:admin/xpack/security/enroll/kibana\"],\"indices\":[],\"applications\":[],\"run_as\":[],\"metadata\":{},\"type\":\"role\"}},\"limited_by_role_descriptors\":{\"_xpack_security\":{\"cluster\":[\"all\"],\"indices\":[{\"names\":[\"*\"],\"privileges\":[\"all\"],\"allow_restricted_indices\":true}],\"applications\":[],\"run_as\":[\"*\"],\"metadata\":{\"_reserved\":true},\"type\":\"role\"}},\"name\":\"enrollment_token_API_key_Of8AeYoBoJSypFN9FBDd\",\"version\":8090299,\"metadata_flattened\":null,\"creator\":{\"principal\":\"_xpack_security\",\"full_name\":null,\"email\":null,\"metadata\":{},\"realm\":\"__attach\",\"realm_type\":\"__attach\"}}]}] blocking until refresh]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.retryBecauseUnavailable(TransportReplicationAction.java:1048)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:848)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase$2.onTimeout(TransportReplicationAction.java:1007)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:355)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:293)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:642)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:916)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"}
```

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-09T08:14:03.925Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw][IPaddress][/Users//Desktop/elasticsearch-8.9.2/data] free: 38.4gb[4.1%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[IPddress][generic][T#3]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.DiskThresholdMonitor","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"NZqmDBtIT26z1AUWAWIQLQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw","elasticsearch.node.name":"IPaddress","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
```

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-09T08:14:13.269Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"Failed to generate credentials for the elastic built-in superuser", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[IPaddress][generic][T#12]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.InitialNodeSecurityAutoConfiguration","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"NZqmDBtIT26z1AUWAWIQLQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"ofMXc8-XQjedccWWx6EYkw","elasticsearch.node.name":"IPaddress","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException","error.message":"[.security-7][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.security-7][0]] containing [index {[.security][reserved-user-elastic], source[{\"password\":\"ci=du6kkFMf9G5*7ZR7g\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"reserved-user\"}]}] and a refresh]","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [.security-7][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.security-7][0]] containing [index {[.security][reserved-user-elastic], source[{\"password\":\"ci=du6kkFMf9G5*7ZR7g\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"reserved-user\"}]}] and a refresh]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.retryBecauseUnavailable(TransportReplicationAction.java:1048)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:848)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase$2.onTimeout(TransportReplicationAction.java:1007)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:355)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:293)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:642)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:916)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"}
```

I tried to:

1. reconfigure `elasticsearch.yml`'s `xpack.security.http.ssl:` configuration from `enabled: true` to:

```
xpack.security.http.ssl: 
  enabled: false 
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12
```

2. download a different version `V8.9.1` but same response
3. manually reset password using `bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic` in another terminal window from the elasticsearch directory, but the response was:

```
Failed to determine the health of the cluster. Cluster health is currently RED. This means that some cluster data is unavailable and your cluster is not fully functional. The cluster logs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/logging.html) might contain information/indications for the underlying cause It is recommended that you resolve the issues with your cluster before continuing It is very likely that the command will fail when run against an unhealthy cluster. If you still want to attempt to execute this command against an unhealthy cluster, you can pass the `-f` parameter. ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster. Cluster health is currently RED.
```

So, I guess the issue is with the health of the Cluster, but I couldn't find a clear answer how to fix it. I looked through similar situations but they all seem to be occurring during the course of running the program rather than happening in the installation stage like my case.